# Error System.ArgumentException Keyword not supported. c++

Tags: mysql, c++-cli

i tried to make program for connecting to my MySQL database and change information in it. But when i try to insert some command i get error.

**Unhandled exception of type "System.ArgumentException" in System.Data.dll
Additional Information: Keyword not supported.**

```
namespace Pro4 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace MySql::Data::MySqlClient;

/// <summary>
/// Сводка для MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtQuery;
protected:

protected:
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Требуется переменная конструктора.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Обязательный метод для поддержки конструктора - не изменяйте
    /// содержимое данного метода при помощи редактора кода.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->txtQuery = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // txtQuery
        // 
        this->txtQuery->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
        this->txtQuery->Multiline = true;
        this->txtQuery->Name = L"txtQuery";
        this->txtQuery->Size = System::Drawing::Size(823, 269);
        this->txtQuery->TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(715, 287);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(120, 40);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button1->Text = L"Run";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, 
&MyForm::button1_Click);
        // 
        // MyForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(847, 531);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->txtQuery);
        this->Name = L"MyForm";
        this->Text = L"MyForm";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ SQLQuery = txtQuery->Text;
    String^ connectionInfo = "datasourse=localhost;port=3307;username=root;password=1qa2ws3ed;database=labeng";
    MySqlConnection^ conn= gcnew MySqlConnection(connectionInfo);
    MySqlCommand^ connCmd = gcnew MySqlCommand(SQLQuery, conn);
    MySqlDataReader^ dataReader;

    try{
        conn->Open();
        dataReader = connCmd->ExecuteReader();
        //MessageBox::Show("Command is done");
    }
    catch (Exception^ex){
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
    }

}
};
}
```

Please, don't be strict, it's new for me.

Comment: In the future, please don't dump all of your GUI code into the question, and please do say exactly which line is throwing the exception. Please don't make us search or guess: search through all your code to find the interesting bits, or guess as to which line is giving the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

That said,

```
String^ connectionInfo = "datasourse=localhost;port=3307;username=root;password=1qa2ws3ed;database=labeng";
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html), the connection string is supposed to contain `server=localhost`, not `datasource=localhost`.

Comment: thank you, it's work
about your warning: i wil follow this next  time